# How different is the version of Chrome on a Chromebook vs. a PC (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, chromebook

I've been trying to find something explaining this, but essentially I'm guessing that there ARE differences, since one is for a Linux-based OS and one is for a Windows-based one.  Are there documented differences, or are there small things that might be implemented on one that aren't implemented quite the same way on the other?

Comment: The only differences would be the differences that exists from running Chrome on `Linux vs Windows vs OS X`

Comment: Right.  I guess I'm wondering what they might be.  Basically I need to know whether we should be buying a Chromebook to test developed web applications in case there is some difference between Chrome implementations.  If the differences are so minor as to never or almost never show up, then it's probably not worth it...

Comment: Use a VM with this ISO http://getchrome.eu/download.php you can confirm it yourself.